# Initialize a javafx scene without the use of a button event

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a new scene called **quiz_scene** and the **quiz_scene_controller** in a javafx project. This scene simulates a question and answer quiz game. The object of the scenes are the question_label and the **answer_text_field** or the **answer_buttons**. In total the number of questions are 7 and after the system directs into the next scene.

I want when I am entering the system to perform a query in an initialize function to a sql database with the questions and answers to fetch the current questions and answers. This procedure needs to be occured once when the system open the quiz_scene (and also every time the answer button is pressed). I tried to add the functionality of the query inside the  `**@FXML public void initialize()**`, however it did not work.

When I tried to add the functionality in a button event the query worked and I am able to change the label and the buttons of the scene using the info from the db. One of the issues I found is the fact that when I am performing the query I am creating a reference to my main class which contains the loader for the quiz_scene. Without event I am not retrieving the current object and I am retrieving a null one. How I can do so without the use of a button? Why my object is null?

The code can be found here: [code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e7dbd438d3680044a1f42f5113e338e5).

```
public class quizSceneController{

 private Flow flow;
 public void setMain(Flow flow){ this.flow = flow;}
 @FXML Button answerbutton;
 @FXML Text timeField, scoreField;
 @FXML public Label question, showQuestionCounter, answer, questionId, questionType, questionSpeed;
 NextQuestion nextQuestion;
 public String temp, temp2;
 public GridPane takingTestPane = new GridPane();

 public void chooseNextQuestion(Flow flow){

    try {
        this.flow.nextQ = false;
        this.flow.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Choosing the next question
        String sql = "select * from Questions where Subject = ? and Level = ?  and questionId = ?";
        PreparedStatement pst = 
this.flow.connectionQuestions.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, this.flow.textSubjectQTest);
        pst.setString(2, this.flow.user_course_level);
        pst.setString(3, this.flow.list.get(counter));
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {

            temp = rs.getString("Question");
            temp2 = rs.getString("Answer");

            pst.execute();
            pst.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No data for this subject");
        }

    } catch (Exception a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
 }

 @FXML private void myButton(ActionEvent event){

    chooseNextQuestion(this.flow);
    this.question.setText(temp);
 }
 @FXML public void initialize(){

    chooseNextQuestion(this.flow);
    this.question.setText(temp);
 }
}
```

Finally the way I am loading the fxml from the main class is the following:

```
loader = new FXMLLoader();         
loader.setLocation(Flow.class.getResource("/gui/quiz/quiz.fxml"));
quizPane = loader.load();
quizSceneController quiz = loader.getController();
```

EDIT: How can instead of using the button to initialize the whole scene using the code of chooseNextQuestion?

Comment: Just add a simple example of my scene_controller.

Comment: On the positive side though, the code is in a java web ide, so it is better structured. For that reason I posted it there. In my opinion way easier to check the code than using stackoverflow format.

Comment: You are right its better both. Believe me however, the reasons were aesthetical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably doing something like this to load the fxml file:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myFXML.fxml"));
Parent p = loader.load();
quizSceneController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setMain(this);
```

However the `initialize` method is executed during `FXMLLoader.load` i.e. before `setMain` is called. The `flow` field still contains `null` at that time.

To work around this, you could execute the code in the setter:

```
public void setMain(Flow flow){
    this.flow = flow;
    chooseNextQuestion(this.flow);
    this.question.setText(temp);
}
```

---

Alternatively remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the root element of the fxml and create/initialize the controller yourself before loading the fxml file:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myFXML.fxml"));
quizSceneController controller = new quizSceneController();
controller.setMain(this);
loader.setController(controller);
Parent p = loader.load();
```

Comment: However is this setMain works every time that I am entering the scene? Or better, how can I be sure that this function works when I am enetering the scene?

Comment: Actually I want the functionality of the controller to happened when I am entering this current scene. How can I do so?

Comment: @christosh Seriously, I think most people don't understand what issue you are facing when you use this solution. These two solutions fabian gave seem correct and logical to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller needs to implement the [`Initializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) interface

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public final class QuizSceneController implements Initializable {

     @Override
     public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
           // do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: I cannot add the implements Initializable (I do import javafx.fxml.Initializable;). I am receiving an error QuizSceneController  must be declared either abstract or implement abstract method public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources). Actually I add the method and I am receiving also there issues in   @Override method does not override from its superclass.

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler tells you that it should be abstract. For my projects this works perfectly without any problems ... which java /javafx version are you using?

Comment: Actually because the initiaize doesn not work properly.

Comment: Please be more specific/exact on the errors. The example I posted should work without any problems

Comment: Override method does not override from its superclass in the line where the override is. Furthermore, I am receiving errors in the URL and ResourceBundle.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. Implementing `Initializable` is not necessary; you do not even need a `public` method (the `@FXML` annotation makes it accessible to the controller) or one taking the 2 parameters. (This is even demonstrated on oracle's FXML introduction page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation )

Comment: I think from JavaFX 8 onwards, all FXML controllers do not need to explicitly implement `Initializable`, the FXMLLoader will check at runtime to see if your controller has one and execute it if it is present.